# Maven: Зависимости и Артефакт

Tags: maven

Мавен это инструмент для сборки проекта и управления зависимостями.

А вот чем Artifact отличается от зависимости? Как я прочитал artifact - это библиотека, готовый проект. Можно подключить к своему проекту.

А зависимость - сторонняя библиотека.
Но по сути написано что артефакт библиотека, что и зависимость библиотека. В чем отличие?

Comment: Хороший [гайд](https://proselyte.net/tutorials/maven/) по _Maven_, вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Проект может состоять из нескольких jar и war файлов.
Артефактом называется часть проекта в виде jar или war файла.
Сторонние репозитории и есть, насколько я понял, зависимости.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).